# Get all unique variations

Tags: c#, .net, linq, math

Here is class I have:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public string mintime { get; set; }
    public string maxtime { get; set; }
    public string weekday { get; set; }
}
```

I got a list of such schedule with repeat week days like

```
List<Schedule> list = new List<Schedule> {
    new Schedule { mintime = "01.01.2012", maxtime = "05.01.2012", weekday = "1" },
    new Schedule { mintime = "05.01.2012", maxtime = "10.01.2012", weekday = "1" },
    new Schedule { mintime = "10.01.2012", maxtime = "20.01.2012", weekday = "2" },
    new Schedule { mintime = "01.02.2012", maxtime = "10.02.2012", weekday = "2" },
    new Schedule { mintime = "01.03.2012", maxtime = "10.03.2012", weekday = "3" },
    new Schedule { mintime = "01.04.2012", maxtime = "10.04.2012", weekday = "4" }
};
```

How can I get List> with all combinations like:

```
List<List<Schedule>> list = new List<List<Schedule>> {
    new List<Schedule> { 
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.01.2012", maxtime = "05.01.2012", weekday = "1" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "10.01.2012", maxtime = "20.01.2012", weekday = "2" }, 
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.03.2012", maxtime = "10.03.2012", weekday = "3" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.04.2012", maxtime = "10.04.2012", weekday = "4" }
    },
    new List<Schedule> { 
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.01.2012", maxtime = "05.01.2012", weekday = "1" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.02.2012", maxtime = "10.02.2012", weekday = "2" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.03.2012", maxtime = "10.03.2012", weekday = "3" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.04.2012", maxtime = "10.04.2012", weekday = "4" }
    },
    new List<Schedule> { 
        new Schedule { mintime = "05.01.2012", maxtime = "10.01.2012", weekday = "1" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "10.01.2012", maxtime = "20.01.2012", weekday = "2" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.03.2012", maxtime = "10.03.2012", weekday = "3" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.04.2012", maxtime = "10.04.2012", weekday = "4" }
    },
    new List<Schedule> { 
        new Schedule { mintime = "05.01.2012", maxtime = "10.01.2012", weekday = "1" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.02.2012", maxtime = "10.02.2012", weekday = "2" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.03.2012", maxtime = "10.03.2012", weekday = "3" },
        new Schedule { mintime = "01.04.2012", maxtime = "10.04.2012", weekday = "4" }
    },
};
```

?

Is it possible to get it using LINQ?

---

The main topic of my question is to build list of schedules. Each schedule should include monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday and sunday once. 
And I need to build such list using a more common list that contains a many schedules for mondays, wednesdays and so on.

Comment: could you precise your question ? very unclear.

Comment: Why are you using strings to represent dates? That's going to make it significantly harder to help you.

Comment: @Cybermaxs Sorry for my english. Tried to improve question. Please see question update.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why is makes harder? Could you explain please?

Comment: @kseen: Well for one thing, it's simply not an appropriate data type. It's clearly meant to be a date rather than text - so why are you using text at all? Also, it makes comparisons between values harder than it needs to be. I originally interpreted your question as wanting every permutation such that mintime was earlier than maxtime, which would require comparisons. As it is, I'm still none the wiser as to what permutations you really want.

Comment: @JonSkeet There is no need to compare mindate and maxdate. Just extract all permutations for week.

Comment: @kseen: Okay, so it's "just" a poor data model issue then, along with poor naming. (`weekday` should be a `DayOfWeek`, too...) Will you ever have anything more than these four weekdays?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have all week days (1..7), I use four just for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Eric Lippert`'s [CartesianProduct here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

```
List<List<Schedule>> newList = CartesianProduct(list.GroupBy(l => l.weekday))
                               .Select(x => x.ToList())
                               .ToList();
```

--

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence
        select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

Comment: Very cool. BTW, if it's an extension method, the proper order should be: `list.GroupBy(l => l.weekday).CartesianProduct().Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();` Also, since links sometimes go bad, can you you include in this post the code for the method?

Comment: @BradRem I know But instead of moving code to a static class  I simply removed `this` to test in my environment.